# Continuous clicking on a paging leads to session out in cakephp 1.3

Tags: session, cakephp-1.3

I am doing an app in cakephp 1.3.I have set the security level as high.When clicking on paging it gets session out.If i set the security level as 'medium' or 'low' then there is no issue.But i need security level as high.What can i do for this?

```
Configure::write('Session.save', 'php');       
Configure::write('Session.timeout',360);       
Configure::write('Security.level', 'high');  
Configure::write('Session.checkAgent', false);
```

Comment: post your code for us

Comment: I have edited question.Pls help me ..Its almost 2 days i am wasting my time by checking this.

Comment: how many minutes it take before timeout?

Comment: how many minutes it take before timeout?

Comment: It takes only seconds.I have a pagination in one page .When i clicks the page 1,then page 2 and  when clicking page 3 it gets session out.

Comment: Fixed the issue by changing session.save as 'database'.